# Prevent reloading of MKMapView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mkmapview

I've made a subclass of UITableViewCell and added a MapView. Everytime I scroll the map of the screen and scroll back to that cell it loads again. (As you all know it's the default behaviour for cell reusing)

Is there anyway to prevent that? Or do you know any other tricks for that case? thanks a lot!

Comment: How many cells are there..? Single or multiple with map on them.?

Comment: A map in a cell is strange, how does the user scroll the tableview?

Comment: there are between 2 and 10 cells. A map in a cell is not strange at all. If you disable the scrolling and userinteraction you still can display some location or even the user location: have a look at the kinetic app for example.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it loads again" means?  Posting the cellForRowAtIndexPath method might also be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you to all for your help! As of now there is nothing going on in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I only setup the mapview in IB and set the delegate. I checked "show user location". So if the cell gets on the screen first of all you see the default region next the userlocation dot appears and centers at the current location. if you scroll out the cell and back in everything starts from the beginning. As of the concept of a uitableview(cell) this is totally correct. But in this case it's annoying :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
  if( row != kMapCellRow ) { // defined value to whatever value it may be
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  else {
    // use an ivar to track the map cell, should be set to nil in class init
    cell = _mapCell;
  }
  if (cell == nil) {
    if( row != kMapCellRow ) { // defined value to whatever value it may be
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else {
        // create your map cell here
        cell = [[[MyTableViewMapCell alloc] init...
    }
  }
  // configure it here
```

You could replace the defined kMapCellRow with an instance variable if it makes sense for your app.

Comment: The key to this as shown above is to not use a reusable cell for that row.

Comment: I think the way to go about is define everything in the class of this unique UITableCell and set that in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: i have same issue if you have any more code and please send.

Comment: what is kMapCellRow and how to implement that